# SQL Join Table for Single Table to Self

Tags: sql, postgresql, many-to-many

I'm trying to create a table in Postgres to represent a many-to-many relationship between rows of the same table.

I have a table called *outerwear* (which is like jackets, etc) and I want to create a many-to-many relationship between instances of *outerwear*.

I'm wondering what the best way is to create a join table to model this relationship that takes into account the fact that *A* to *B* is the same as *B* to *A*. So far I have this (which is just a normal join table):

```
CREATE TABLE outerwear_outerwear_join (
    a_outerwear_id integer REFERENCES outerwear,
    b_outerwear_id integer REFERENCES outerwear,
    PRIMARY KEY(a_outerwear_id, b_outerwear_id)
);
```

But again this does not account for the fact that flipping the order of the columns should not change the value/uniqueness of a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UNIQUE INDEX` , using `least` and `greatest` functions.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_test_a_b 
  ON outerwear_outerwear_join ( LEAST(a_outerwear_id, b_outerwear_id), GREATEST( 
a_outerwear_id, b_outerwear_id));
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=181af777add270b4810c3da704c0d16a)

Comment: Okay, nice! How would i define this within the `CREATE TABLE` statement above? (I haven't executed it yet)

Comment: @HenryWoody : It is a statement to be run separately after the `create table`