# SQL unique combination of two columns and vice versa

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
ID
KEY_1
KEY_2
```

I want the combination of KEY_1 with KEY_2 to be unique and vice versa.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT uq_table_name UNIQUE(KEY_1, KEY_2);
```

This way I can make the combination between KEY_1 AND KEY_2 unique but I want the vice versa  as well.

**Example:**

```
KEY_1 = 111;
KEY_2 = 222;
```

I cannot insert this values again or neither can I insert the values vice versa.

**This shouldn't be valid (since it's the same pair of keys):**

```
KEY_1 = 222;
KEY_2 = 111;
```

Thanks

Comment: Simply add a key1 < key2 constraint?

Comment: If `key_1` and `key_2` refer to the same thing which is what you are showing then don't make them separate entries.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51347013/939860, https://stackoverflow.com/a/46439761/939860, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241079/3684, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187676/3684, ...

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this with an unique functional index instead of an unique constraint.

```sql
create unique index table_name_uix 
  on table_name (greatest(key_1, key_2), least(key_1, key_2));
```

Details on Postgres unique constraint vs unique index [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23542794/postgres-unique-constraint-vs-index)

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way to do this.

- UNIQUE only accepts attributes names

One way to solve this is by creating two new attributes: minatt, maxatt (so they are ordered) and then adding these two attributes as a single UNIQUE constraint.

You could also have a trigger that would update these attributes automatically (during insert/update). This way you would avoid consistency problems.

Another way to do it is by having a trigger that checks the constraint (sort of like a tuple constraint where you manually check the uniqueness of these concatenations (sounds more complicated and error prone than the UNIQUE solution).

Answer (score 0):

You can add two columns to your table, `key_min` and `key_max`, use a trigger to calculate `key_min` = smallest value between `key_1` and `key_2`; `key_max`= largest value between `key_1` and `key_2` and create the constraint UNIQUE(key_min,key_max). You can see a similar solution using MariaDB and virtual columns [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=8e94e51416dc7570bc33e67c93024b22).